# Java loss of precision with Heron's formula

Tags: java

I'm trying to print the area and perimeter of a triangle with the given lengths. I have successfully printed the correct perimeter however, my area is incorrect (the output of the area is 0.00). I realized that it is a loss of precision error but, I am unable to solve it. Will anyone please examine this code and point out the issue, specifically at the instance method,calculateArea? Thank you.

```
public class Triangle
{
private int sideA=0, sideB=0, sideC=0, perimeter=0;
private double area=0;

public Triangle()
{ 
}
public Triangle(int a, int b, int c)
{
    setSides(a,b,c);
}
public void setSides(int a,int b, int c) 
{
   sideA=a;
   sideB=b;
   sideC=c;
}
public void calculateArea()
{
    int s;
    s=(int)perimeter/2;
    double area=Math.sqrt(s*(s-sideA)*(s-sideB)*(s-sideC));
}
   public void calculatePerimeter()
{
perimeter=sideA+sideB+sideC;
}
public void printTriangle()
   {
    System.out.printf("The triangle with sides %d , %d and %d has an area of %.3f and perimeter %d%n", sideA, sideB, sideC, area, perimeter);
    }
}
```

For reference(you don't need to correct it or anything), here's my other code.

```
public class TriangleRunner
{
public static void main(System[]args)
{
   Triangle isoceles = new Triangle();
   isoceles.setSides(3,3,3);
   isoceles.calculateArea();
   isoceles.calculatePerimeter();
   isoceles.printTriangle();

   Triangle right345 = new Triangle();
   right345.setSides(3,4,5);
   right345.calculateArea();
   right345.calculatePerimeter();
   right345.printTriangle();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `perimeter` in `calculateArea`, but that is only calculated in `calculatePerimeter`, which isn't called yet, so `perimiter` is still `0`.  You can simply call `calculatePerimeter` first, before calling `calculateArea`, but it may be best to call `calculatePerimeter` in `calculateArea` to make sure it's available to you.

Because the `perimeter` value depends on the other values, it isn't a good idea to have it as an instance variable.  You may want to return that value in `calculatePerimeter`, using it as a local variable when necessary.

Also, change `s` in `calculateArea` to a `double`, and divide by the `double` literal `2.0` instead of `2`, to force floating-point calculations.

With these changes I get correct output.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just wondering, how would I call calculatePerimeter in calculateArea?